# Javascript onClick fires two events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I threw together a quick website for a friend of mine and I basically just used a query slider to manage all of the content, however when a visitor clicks play on one of his songs, it also seems to fire off the navigation (triggered by `onClick`). The problem is that playing the music also engages the slider and I am not good enough at JavaScript/jQuery yet to figure out how to separate the two events. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>

function goto(id, t){   
//animate to the div id.
$(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 600);

// remove "active" class from all links inside #nav
$('#nav a').removeClass('active');

// add active class to the current link
$(t).addClass('active');    
}
```

```
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="wrap">
    
    <div id="header">
            <img src="images/header.gif" width="320" height="59">
            
            
      </div>
        
    <div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li ><a class="active" href="#" onClick="goto('#about', this); return false"><img src="images/bioblack.gif" width="93" height="55"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onClick="goto('#work', this); return false"><img src="images/soundblack.gif" width="146" height="55"></li>
            <li><a href="#" onClick="goto('#contact', this); return false"><img src="images/contactblack.gif" width="183" height="54"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
        <div class="contentbox-wrapper">
            
            <div id="about" class="contentbox">
                            
            
            <img src="images/bio.gif" width="549" height="270">
          </div>
            
            <div id="work" class="contentbox">
            
         

            <img src="images/slowlane.gif" width="165" height="38">
          

            <embed height="45" alt="slow lane" width="500" autoplay="false" autostart="false" type="audio/mpeg" src="music/6_People_Get_Ready_This_Is_Rock_Steady_.aiff"></embed> 
            
            <img src="images/speedlimit.gif" width="169" height="39">
            <embed height="45" alt="speed limit"width="500" autoplay="false" autostart="false" type="audio/mpeg" src="music/7_Odyssey.aiff"></embed>
             
            <img src="images/fastlane.gif" width="169" height="37">
            <embed height="45" alt="fast lane"width="500" autoplay="false" autostart="false" type="audio/mpeg" src="music/9_Salsa_Verde.aiff"></embed> 
                        
              </div>
        
            <div id="contact" class="contentbox">
            
            <img src="images/contact.gif" width="422" height="188"></div>
    
        </div>          
        
    </div>
```

Comment: The html is broken, `<li >`, unclosed `<a>` tags

Comment: Have you tried creating 3 different functions, and each one only does the job for that section?

Comment: Try to avoid JS inline declaration like onclick="" and use JQuery click() event

Comment: Once I closed the tags properly everything worked without issue. good call Esailija

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html has a lot of unclosed tags, try it with a fixed and indented html:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/header.gif" width="320" height="59">
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" onClick="goto('#about', this); return false" class="active">
                            <img src="images/bioblack.gif" width="93" height="55">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" onClick="goto('#work', this); return false">
                            <img src="images/soundblack.gif" width="146" height="55">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" onClick="goto('#contact', this); return false">
                            <img src="images/contactblack.gif" width="183" height="54">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="contentbox-wrapper">

                <div id="about" class="contentbox">
                    <img src="images/bio.gif" width="549" height="270">
                </div>

                <div id="work" class="contentbox">
                    <img src="images/slowlane.gif" width="165" height="38">
                    <embed height="45" alt="slow lane" width="500" autoplay="false" autostart="false" type="audio/mpeg" src="music/6_People_Get_Ready_This_Is_Rock_Steady_.aiff"></embed> 

                    <img src="images/speedlimit.gif" width="169" height="39">
                    <embed height="45" alt="speed limit"width="500" autoplay="false" autostart="false" type="audio/mpeg" src="music/7_Odyssey.aiff"></embed>

                    <img src="images/fastlane.gif" width="169" height="37">
                    <embed height="45" alt="fast lane"width="500" autoplay="false" autostart="false" type="audio/mpeg" src="music/9_Salsa_Verde.aiff"></embed> 
                </div>

                <div id="contact" class="contentbox">
                    <img src="images/contact.gif" width="422" height="188"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() could solve your problem. Just prevent the default behavior of the button and let js fire the correct event.